# Bubble sort swaps every number regardless of value

Tags: java, sorting, swap, bubble-sort

```
import java.util.*;
public class Zhangbubble
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int Bub[] = new int[6];
        Random randy = new Random();
        boolean Done = false;
        for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
        {
            Bub[x] = randy.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println (Bub[x]);
        }
        System.out.println ("This is the original array");
        while (! Done)
        {
            Done = true;
            for(int x = 0; x < Bub.length - 1; x++) 
            {
                if(Bub[x+1] < Bub[x]) 
                {
                    int temp = Bub[x];
                    Bub[x] = Bub[x+1];
                    Bub[x+1] = temp;
                    System.out.println ("Number "+Bub[x]+ " and  " +Bub[x+1]+ " have     been switched");
                }
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < Bub.length; x++) 
            {
                System.out.println(Bub[x]);

            }
            Done = true;
        } 

    }
}
```

My bubble sort works in ascending order but it only sorts once. It seems to be working fine but I can't pinpoint what's making it not loop.  It will run through the number sequence once but it won't keep sorting after the first initial check. Can someone help me to make it loop until the entire sequence is in order?  Alright I think I may have figured it out.  I got rid of Done = true and instead added Done = false right after the sorting algorithm.  It seems to be working great now but if anyone spots something wrong please don't hesitate to point it out!

Comment: It doesn't swap everything due to the if condition: `Bub[x + 1] > Bub[x]`. It will sort larger elements to the start of the array. Also, it is not a full sort, as it only does one loop over the array.

Comment: That `while` loop isn't accomplishing anything.

Comment: Please follow the java naming conventions. `Done` should be `done`, and `Bub` should be `bub`.

Comment: Ok so I've put it in ascending order but how can I make it run more than once?  It switches everything fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't swap "everything". However, if you are trying to sort the array in the ascending order, the `if` condition is the wrong way round.

Additionally, you need to carefully think about when you should be setting `Done` to `true`. The current approach is flawed.

Comment: I've put the numbers in ascending order.  I set done to false under the swapping algorithm and got rid of the done = true.

Comment: How do I make the bubble sort loop more than once?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the swapping works ok. Your problem is, that the inner part of the `while` cycle will never repeat more than once, because of the way you set `Done` to `true` at the end. This way, only the position of the smallest element in the array is determined correctly.

If you want it to perform full bubble sort, I'd suggest exchanging the outer `while` cycle for a `for` cycle, like this

```
for (int y = 0; y < Bub.length - 1; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < Bub.length - 1; x++) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

or if you want to keep the `while` cycle, you should set up the ending condition correctly, as in

```
if ( *everything is sorted* ) {
    Done = true;
}
```